# OData Accessing CustomMeta info empty

Tags: 2013, odata

We are trying to configure the access to the Broker via the Odata protocol. We already get keywords information with simple queries like:

***Keywords.Take(100)***

The problem is when we try to get CustomMetas, our result query is empty.

```
from x in CustomMetas
where x.PublicationId == 41
select x
```

I guess we have some misconfiguration problem in the cd_storage, but logs show a warning related to AmbientData.

- Is it necessary to configure Ambient Data for using CustomMeta info?
- Do we need a special typeMapping for this case, different from the Query one?

I post the logs for the query shown before.

> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,711 DEBUG ODataWebserviceHandler - Requested a
>   OData feed/entry: CustomMetas() with type:
>   application/atom+xml;charset=UTF-8
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,711 DEBUG ODataWebserviceHandler - Setting $top to
>   25
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,711 DEBUG ResolverBase - Requested OData
>   collection
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,712 DEBUG FilterValue - check if value: 25 is of
>   Integer type
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,712 DEBUG FilterValue - value: 25 is Integer
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,712 DEBUG FilterValue - check if value:
>   PublicationId is of Integer type
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,712 DEBUG FilterValue - value: PublicationId is
>   not an Integer
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,712 DEBUG FilterValue - value: PublicationId is
>   not Boolean
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,713 DEBUG FilterValue - check if value:
>   PublicationId is of Float type
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,713 DEBUG FilterValue - value: PublicationId is
>   not Float
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,713 DEBUG FilterValue - check if value: 41 is of
>   Integer type
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,713 DEBUG FilterValue - value: 41 is Integer
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,714 DEBUG FilterValue - check if value: 41 is of
>   Integer type
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,714 DEBUG FilterValue - value: 41 is Integer
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,716 DEBUG JPQLFilterComposer - composed hql is:
>   o0.publicationId = :publicationId0
>
> 2013-12-23 12:06:05,721 WARN  AmbientDataContext - There is no current
>   ambient data context - the ambient data framework is not properly
>   initialised

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1 and have installed the WS in a RHEL as a java application.

Thank you

Comment: We commonly see that warning occur on an application start up when code tries to use the Ambient Data Context before it's been initialised.

Comment: Try 2 things to get more info: 1) look at your client log to see what OData URL is being generated and submitted, and please update your question with it.  2) Look in your Broker DB at the CustomMetas table. Does it have values in it for publication 41?

Answer (score 3):

The problem was a missconfiguration in the cd_storage_conf.xml file contained in the web service. The taxonomy information is stored in the db by the deployer, and I had in the WS that the Query type would be consulted from the default source, which was the filesystem. 
The ODATA service is using the query type for getting the information, so there was the problem. My query was trying to retrieve information from the filesystem, when it's stored in the DB.
Then, I configured the Query access to db instead of the FS and I republished the category. Now it's working perfectly.

It would be wonderful to have a section in the OData configuration telling how the cd_storage_conf.xml has to be configured for using properly this service.